# Цветовое оформление данных (где факт поступления совпадает/не совпадает с планом)

Tags: excel, vba

Создал файл для расчета факт план поступлений, написал макрос, который должен был помочь в том, чтобы понять, где факт поступления совпадают планом, но что-то прописано неверно. В файле есть данные на листе 1 они плановые и данные листа 2 они фактические. На первом листе нужно, чтобы совпавшие факт-план суммы были синими или просто не красились, те участки где на листе 1 не было суммы подсвечивались другим цветом(  в примере голубой), а если на втором листе не никаких данных о  такой сумме то подсвечивалось красным. я остановился на первом этапе и что идет неверно видно по синим ячейкам. Подскажите как в этой ситуации можно прописать макрос?

```
 Sub income()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2")

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcolumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Lastrow1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcolumn1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, n As Integer, s As Integer

For i = 2 To Lastrow1
   For j = 2 To LastRow

   If sh2.Cells(i, 1) = sh1.Cells(j, 1) Then
   k = j

   End If
   Next
 On Error Resume Next
  For s = 4 To Lastcolumn
  If sh2.Cells(i, 3) = sh1.Cells(1, s) * 1 Then
   n = s

  On Error Resume Next
   ElseIf sh2.Cells(i, 2) = sh1.Cells(k, n) Then

   sh1.Cells(k, n).Interior.Color = vbBlue
   End If

   Next
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Ну так трассируйте код, и на каждом шаге смотрите, чему равны значения переменных, соответствуют ли они ожидаемым, и если нет, то какого чёрта и как это пофиксить.

Comment: через debug print прослеживал каждое значение переменных но почему то все правильно но при операции окрашивания сводилось к тому что я ставил `elseif not` и окрас шел не по сценарию. Мои подозрения в логике макроса что я что то упускаю или неправильно задаю переменные

Comment: При чём тут Debug.Print? Ставишь в коде брейкпойнт, выполняешь по одному оператору и отслеживаешь значения переменных после выполнения каждой строки кода..

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
все оказалось проще чем думалось

Sub income1()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2")
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcolumn1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("лист2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, n As Integer, s As Integer

    For i = 2 To lastrow
    For y = 4 To lastcolumn
    If Not IsEmpty(sh1.Cells(i, y)) Then
    sh1.Cells(i, y).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Next
    Next


    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow
        If sh2.Cells(i, 1) = sh1.Cells(j, 1) Then
        Z = sh2.Cells(i, 3) + 3

            If sh2.Cells(i, 2) = sh1.Cells(j, Z) Then
             sh1.Cells(j, Z).Interior.Color = rgbChartreuse
            Else
            If IsEmpty(sh1.Cells(j, Z)) Then
            sh1.Cells(j, Z).Interior.Color = rgbAqua
            End If
            End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: Ну да.. А что решили это не Вы (и указать источник) - написать забыли.